# Why are the open system call mode values different for equivalent code?

Tags: c, linux, umask

Below code and the quoted statement are from `Linux System Programming by Robert Love`.
I don't understand how are the modes in the first and the second code examples the same.

From the first example, I calculated the mode values as

```
USR -> 2+1 = 3
GRP -> 2+1 = 3
OTH -> 1 =   1
```

So my expectation was 0331, but it the book says it's 0664.

What's wrong in my logic?

**Copied from the book below:**

```
int fd;
fd = open (file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IWGRP | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
if(fd == -1)
 /* error */
```

> Trading portability (in theory at least) for readability, we could
> have written the following, to identical effect:

```
int fd;
fd = open(file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0664);
if(fd == -1)
 /*error*/
```

Comment: *Trading portability (in theory at least) for readability* Not true.  The numeric value is [just as portable](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html): "The <sys/stat.h> header shall define the following symbolic constants for the file mode bits encoded in type `mode_t`, **with the indicated numeric values**."  Anyone stating that you need to use values such as `S_IWUSR` all bitwise-or'd together for portability over values such as `0644` is wrong.

Comment: Read is 4 and write is 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whichever reason, you have chosen to use the wrong values for the constants.

- Instead of S_IRUSR being `0400`, you decided it was `0200`.
- Instead of S_IWUSR being `0200`, you decided it was `0100`.
- etc

If you use the correct values for the constants, you will get the same result.

Comment: Hmm, I assumed read is always 1, write 2 and exec 4.